# Count number of sub-folders in folder

Tags: php

### PHP Code

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="DirView">';
    $path = "../Desktop/";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            echo '<li>'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

### Problem

I wish to be able to count the number of folders in my chosen location to do more with this script performing a whilst loop for the amount of sub-folders there are.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: `foreach` will iterate through this loop for each element of the array ?!

Comment: Please include example input and the output you would like.  How have you tried to solve the problem so far?

Comment: I simply want to make a var with the number of sub folders @dg99 \

Comment: `$dirCount = count($dir);` does this works for you?!

Comment: Since you are already looping over the result, couldn't you just take a count and `$count++` every time you echo something out? Assuming that `count($dir)` might have extra values you don't want like the `.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count($dir)` would be the easiest solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work here. (always 1)

So here is the solution with a counter variable:

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="DirView">';
    $path = "..";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            echo '<li>'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'</li>';
            $counter++;
            // do your while loop here
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo "There are $counter files in this directory.";
?>
```